# ComboBox SelectedItem Binding does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a datagrid with four columns.

```
<DataGrid ItemSource="{Binding MyDataSet,Mode=TwoWay}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock ...../>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock ...../>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    .............
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemSource ="{Binding FirstComboBoxData }" SelectedItem="{Binding FirstComboBoxSelectedVal}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemSource ="{Binding SecondComboBoxData }" SelectedItem="{Binding SecondComboBoxSelectedVal}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The model class `MyData` is like in the following.

```
class MyData : ObservableObject
{
    private string _code;
    public string Code
    {
        set { _code = value ; OnPropertyChanged("Code");}
        get { return _code ;}
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        set { _name = value ; OnPropertyChanged("Name");}
        get { return _name ;}
    }

    private List<SomeOtherClass> _firstComboBoxData;
    public List<SomeOtherClass> FirstComboBoxData
    {
        set { _firstComboBoxData = value ; OnPropertyChanged("FirstComboBoxData");}
        get { return _firstComboBoxData ;}
    }


    private List<SomeOtherClass> _secondComboBoxData;
    public List<SomeOtherClass> SecondComboBoxData
    {
        set { _secondComboBoxData = value ; OnPropertyChanged("SecondComboBoxData");}
        get { return _secondComboBoxData ;}
    }

    private SomeOtherClass _firstComboBoxSelectedVal;
    public SomeOtherClass Name
    {
        set { _firstComboBoxSelectedVal= value ; OnPropertyChanged("FirstComboBoxSelectedVal");}
        get { return _firstComboBoxSelectedVal;}
    }

    private SomeOtherClass _secondComboBoxSelectedVal;
    public SomeOtherClass SecondComboBoxSelectedVal
    {
        set { _secondComboBoxSelectedVal= value ; OnPropertyChanged("SecondComboBoxSelectedVal");}
        get { return _secondComboBoxSelectedVal;}
    }


}
class SomeOtherClass
{
    private int id;

    public int ID
    {
        set { id = value ; OnPropertyChanged("ID");}
        get { return id ;}
    }
}
```

Then I have the following list in my ViewModel.

```
 private ObservableCollection<MyData> _myDataSet;
 public  ObservableCollection<MyData> MyDataSet
 {
     set { _myDataSet=value; OnPropertyChanged ("MyDataSet"); }
     get { return _myDataSet ;}
 }
```

I see everything is fine. But when I change the selected item of said comboboxes,  `MyDataSet`'s relevant `FirstComboBoxSelectedVal` or `SecondComboBoxSelectedVal` is not updated

Have I done something wrong somewhere?

Comment: What do you have in `SomeOtherClass` class? you might need to specify the property you intend to bind.

Comment: Make `SomeOtherClass` inherits from ObservableObject too.

Comment: Is DataContext of DataGrid clear ?